# Sending the value of an int to a function that takes void* without using &

Tags: c, pointers, memory, data-structures, void-pointers

In my situation, I am using the queue to perform BFS on an undirected graph.
The graph is represented by an adjacency matrix. I need to append the neighbors of the current node to the queue as I iterate through a line in the matrix. So my best idea was to use the value of the iterator.

But if I call it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    enqueue(q, &i);
}
```

The value I append will change as the for loop keeps iterating and my queue will look like this:

```
(4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

How can I avoid this?

For simplicity, how could I call the function, such that after exiting the loop it looks like this instead:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Below, is a reproduction. Unfortunately, I can not edit these functions

```
void init_list(LinkedList *list);
void init_q(Queue *q);
void add_nth_node(LinkedList *list, int n, void *new_data);
void enqueue(Queue *q, void *new_data);
```

because my assignment restricts changing them. For the sake of clarity, the reproduction has them unchanged and I apologize if the minimal reproduction isn't so minimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct {
    LinkedList *list;
} Queue;

void init_q(Queue *q);

void init_list(LinkedList *list);

void add_nth_node(LinkedList *list, int n, void *new_data);

void enqueue(Queue *q, void *new_data) {
    // Add a node with new_data at the end of the list (queue)
    add_nth_node(q->list, q->list->size, new_data);
}


int main (void) {
    int i;

    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    init_q(q);

/*  I am using the queue to perform BFS on an undirected graph.
    The graph is represented by an adjacency matrix.
    I need to append the neighbors to the queue as I iterate through
    a line in the matrix. So my best idea was to use the value of the
    iterator. This queue is only necessary in the BFS function (absent
    for simplicity).
*/
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        enqueue(q, &i);
    }

    free_q(q);
    return 0;
}

void init_q(Queue *q) {
    q->list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    if (q == NULL) {
        perror("Not enough memory to initialize the queue!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    init_list(q->list);
}

void init_list(LinkedList *list) {
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
}

void add_nth_node(LinkedList *list, int n, void *new_data) {
    Node *prev, *curr;
    Node *new_node;

    if (list == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (n > list->size) {
        n = list->size;
    } else if (n < 0) {
        return;
    }

    curr = list->head;
    prev = NULL;
    while (n > 0) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        --n;
    }

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        perror("Not enough memory to add element!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = curr;
    if (prev == NULL) {
        /* when n == 0. */
        list->head = new_node;
    } else {
        prev->next = new_node;
    }

    if (new_node->next == NULL) {
        list->tail = new_node;
    }

    list->size++;
}
```

Comment: You could use a cast: `enqueue(q, (void *)i);`. Then convert it back with `int val = (int)new_data;`.

Comment: Why is that a problem? `i` will be incremented after `enqueue` returned so `i` will be the same while the function executes.

Comment: @Eraklon I guess it might be a problem due to several queued items pointing to the same `i`, so they _all_ get incremented when `i` is incremented. It's hard to know without seeing the source for `enqueue` though!

Comment: @Eraklon From what I've observed while debugging, if i increments, the value in the queue also changes.

Comment: @craynorr Well then make a copy of the item and put that in the queue. Would be nice to see a more exact example with the function body included.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]?.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'll try my best to reproduce it. I'll edit the question and include more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to solve the problem. One is portable, but the other is less portable.

The first solution involves allocating space for the queued `int` value dynamically:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int *val = malloc(sizeof(*val));

    *val = i;
    enqueue (q, val);
}
```

Whatever code needs the `int` value can dereference the pointer:

```
int val = *(int *)dataptr;
```

Some piece of code will need to free the memory to avoid memory leaks.

The second solution is sneaky and less portable and involves using the `void *` to store an integer instead of a pointer to an object:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    enqueue (q, (void *)i);
}
```

Whatever code needs the `int` value will need to convert the pointer value back to an `int`:

```
int val = (int)dataptr;
```

You may get some compiler warnings. It may be better to replace `int` with `intptr_t`.

The sneaky solution relies on the round trip conversion of `int` to `void *` and back to `int` (or from `intptr_t` to `void *` and back to `intptr_t`) preserving the original value, which is not guaranteed by the C standard, so it not as portable as the first solution using dynamically allocated storage.

---

Of course, if you really only need to queue a small fixed number of `int`s, you could allocate them as an array and enqueue a pointer to a separate element in each iteration:

```
int vals[5];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vals[i] = i;
    enqueue (q, &vals[i]);
}
```

Whatever code needs the `int` value can dereference the pointer:

```
int val = *(int *)dataptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try unreliable techniques.  If you're worried that enqueue might change the value referenced by its second argument, then give it a copy:

```
void enqueue(Queue *q, void *new_data);

int main (void) {
    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof *q);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int copy = i;
        enqueue (q, &copy);
    }

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, if `enqueue` is storing the address rather than the referenced value then you can't mutate that object. (This is more likely, and makes the signature of enqueue make more sense.  I was confused by your description; the problem is not at all the enqueue is changing the object.  The problem is that your code is changing the object addressed by the data now stored in the queue.)  You'll need to maintain a non-mutating copy of the data that you are referencing in the queue.

In other words, the title of the question is misleading. You are not trying to store the value of an int at all.  You are trying to record the address of an int.

Comment: I don't think that helps, and is probably worse because `copy` has a shorter lifetime than the queued objects. (We don't know what happens in the `// ...`, but `copy`'s lifetime has definitely ended by then.)

Comment: The issue still remains, the queue would contain multiple items of the same address.

Comment: @craynor What issue?  If you don't want to add multiple entries to the queue, then don't call `enqueue` in the loop.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'll provide more context by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

send a (pointer to a) literal array

```
enqueue(q, (int[]){i});
```

see https://ideone.com/cu5jmn

Comment: But it might be using the same storage for the literal array in each iteration of the `for` loop, so back to square one. I think from the question we need to assume that the lifetime of the items queued by`enqueue` extends beyond the `for` loop.